# Wordpress5.4.13 con plugin All-in-One Event Calendar 2.5.7 no funciona cuando quiero configurar o quiero importar un excel?

Tags: wordpress

Active para poder ver los errores y me sale que es que un error de react pero no entiendo, cual es el error, ojala que me puedan ayudar?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]